# lisp: building a repl for parenscript

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, parenscript

I've been working to learn [Parenscript](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/tutorial.html), but I'm finding that the tutorial is more of a how-to for running a web server.

Does there already exist, or is it possible to create, a REPL so that I can see the actual javascript that is output when calling Parenscript methods?

Comment: Have you explored the [SLIME integration](https://common-lisp.net/project/parenscript/reference.html#section-slime-integration) section of the manual?

Comment: Writing `(ps …)` forms at the usual REPL doesn't suit you? They output JavaScript. (+1 for a PS REPL though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the obvious:

`(loop (print (ps:ps* (read))))`

But I prefer having a form that I can edit in a buffer and just `macroexpand-1` (`C-c ret` on the opening paren):

```lisp
(defmacro js-func (name &body body)
  (let ((code (ps* `(progn ,@body))))
    `(defun ,name ()
       ,code))))
```